# How to download images and bounding boxes from imageNet such that they have matching names?

Tags: dataset, bounding-box, imagenet

I am doing object detection for a specific class, say, chairs .

I want to download images of chairs from imageNet. I also want to download the annotation xml files (bounding boxes) from imageNet.

Both these things are provided on imageNet and I have successfully been able to download them using a tool called ImageNet_Utils

https://github.com/tzutalin/ImageNet_Utils

But the downloaded images and bounding boxes don't have matching names. So it is impossible to tell which xml file is for which image.

How do I download images and bounding boxes from imageNet such that corresponding image and annotation xml files have matching names?

Answer (score 1):

The [download image URLs](http://image-net.org/download-imageurls) page says

> The URLs are listed in a single txt file, where each line contains an
>   image ID and the original URL

Unfortunately, as of 2020-03-06, all the URL mapping files link to a **Oops! The URL is not valid** page. However, can however get mappings for each node individually. They are available by wnid: http://www.image-net.org/api/text/imagenet.synset.geturls.getmapping?wnid=n03273913

A bounding box annotation file will contain this element.

```
    <filename>n03273913_16800</filename>
```

The `n03273913` is the synset id and the `16800` is the image id. In the synset mapping file you'll find the line

```
    n03273913_16800 http://farm1.static.flickr.com/186/425238103_8fe80b37de.jpg
```

You can download the image from that location.

Comment: As of now all links are down and the filenames cannot be matched. Does anyone know how to use the 2010 boxes? Currently they seem useless.

Answer (score -2):

There's a c++ library known as dlib. You can pass your downloaded images from dlib, it has GUI support for drawing blocks in images and save them in vector formats in an XML file. You can refer [here](http://www.dlib.net) for the documentation